# One is different than one

Tags: vba

i'm having a code issue and i was wondering if you guys can help me find a logical explanation for it.

i have the following code:

```
If rngTotal.Value2 <> 1 And Not IsError(rngHours) Then
    'code here
End if
```

rngTotal.Value2 is 1, and yet, VBA says that rngTotal.Value2 <> 1 is true... which does not make sense. I tried to write it like cDBL(rngTotal.Value2) <> 1, but I get the same result.

This part of the macro should trigger only when rngTotal <> 1 and yet it triggers when it's =1 also.

Does anyone have an ideea on this?

Comment: You can try Cint(rngTotal.Value2).

Comment: What's the DataType of Value here?. Are you sure that it is exactly one and has no decimals ?

Comment: There is no rounding of the number?

Comment: could you tag the MS-Office product? Excel, ms-access,... what does `debug.print rngTotal.Value2` outputs ?

Comment: Could it be rounding? Try `Round(rngTotal.Value2, 2) <> 1`. You also don't show how you get `rndTotal`, so it could be referring to a different cell than what you indend. Maybe debug and check that `rngTotal.Value2` does actually evaluate to 1 at this point in the code

Comment: Try `(rngTotal.Value2 \ 1) <> 1` as well, very likely far away decimal caused this (e.g. 0.000000000000000001 <> 0).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by modifying

```
rngTotal.Value2 <> 1
```

to

```
rngTotal.Value2 <> "1"
```

rngTotal contained sum of percentages, and the total should be 1 (100%). VBA was recognizing the compare to value 1 without double quotes as True for some reason.

For the people who were asking, it was not a decimal issue, in debug.print both values resulted in 1. And anyway I tested out with round and had the same result.